# Display Lines AND Points on the Line Chart - Google Visualisation API

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

Is it possible to represent one data series as points and another as lines?

In the chart below I want the blue 'Data' line to be represented as points whilst retaining the other series as lines, can this be done using the Google Visualisations?

[image: Google Visualisation (Line Graph)]

I generated the graph above in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6vzjut4/) using the following code

```
   function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Data');
  data.addColumn('number', 'High');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Low');
  data.addRow(["A", 1, 5.5, 2.3]);
  data.addRow(["B", 2, 5.5, 2.3]);
  data.addRow(["C", 7, 5.5, 2.3]);
  data.addRow(["D", 3, 5.5, 2.3]);
  data.addRow(["E", 6, 5.5, 2.3]);
  data.addRow(["F", 5, 5.5, 2.3]);


  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {
        width: 500, height: 400}
          );
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can! 
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

In that link go to the section on "Series". You can specify each line as a series and set the lineWidth property to 0, overriding the default. That should have the effect of drawing no line and just the data points. In your case you can set the 1st series ("Data") to 0 and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed to also set the pointSize option as just setting the lineWidth to zero removed the series.  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data,{
      series: {
        0:{color: 'green', visibleInLegend: true, lineWidth: 0, pointSize: 2},
               1:{color: 'red', visibleInLegend: true},
               2:{color: 'blue',visibleInLegend: true}
              }
    });

Comment: Good call! I saw that property there but I hadn't checked if the default value would work.